# MoneyMask não Funciona no Device

Tags: jquery, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mask-plugin

O Plugin Jquery não funciona no *device*, alguém saberia como resolver isso?

A questão é o seguinte, pesquisei sobre o  porque de o plugin **MoneyMask** não funcionar dentro do *device* e descobri que os *plugins* de mascara utilizam o evento `Keydown` que retorna um objeto que contem o seguinte elemento:

```
event.Keycode
```

Retorna sempre 0 no Android 4.0+ o plugin não funciona.
 Alguém saberia como resolver?

Comment: Amigo na verdade não existe código a mostrar pois o plugin funciona normalmente no navegador.

Comment: Bom, eu pesquisei por dúvidas e problemas, não encontrei nada relacionado a não funcionar fora de navegadores. [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/49048/edit) a sua pergunta e inclua mais detalhes (se possível, o código), tente torná-la mais especifica e relevante para outros usuários que (talvez) tenham o mesmo problema futuramente. - [Como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Amigo eu pesquisei e fiz testes e descobri o seguinte...
O moneyMask e outras maskaras utilizam o metodo Keydown do javascript, sendo necessário identificar qual tecla esta sendo utilizada a reconhecendo com o event.keycode mas no android 4.0+ ele não fornece esse parâmetro pra você assim fazendo com que o plugin não funcione.

Comment: Editei a pergunta ficou melhor?

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema antes, troca KeyCode por KeyPress e vê se funciona, creio que é um problema com o Navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se você pode editar o código do plugin em questão, mas se puder, atualize para keyup ou outro tipo de evento não relacionado ao teclado como "change".